# How to prove the divergence/convergence of the following series: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n^4}-1}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've tried the Ratio and Root test, but both are inconclusive, and I can't find a comparison to prove that the following serie is converge or diverge.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n^4}-1}$$

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ok! I'll take note, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: for large enough $n$,
$$
\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n^4}-1}\ge\frac{1}{n}
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}}{\sqrt[3]{n^4}-1}> \frac{\sqrt[3]n}{\sqrt[3]{n^4}}=\frac{1}{n^{4/3-1/3}}=\frac{1}{n}$$